# I can't get into Backbone events method

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Hi, Im new to Backbone.js and I've just started a tutorial video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk).
The idea of the tutorial is simple - to write the exact code from the beggining and learn the basics.

Im using jquery 1.8.2, backbone 0.9.2 and underscore 1.4.2

The problem starts when I stucked at calling custom method saveUser from basic submit event here:

```
// Create new user
    var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function() {
            var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {});
            this.$el.html(template);
        },
        events: {
            'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser'
        },
        saveUser: function() {
            alert('PLEASE SHOW UP');
        }
    })
```

The point is it that method saveUser will not call its function, doesnt matter whatever code is inside (return false; for example).

The form:

```
<script type="text/template" id="edit-user-template">
    <form class="edit-user-form">
        <legend>Create User</legend>
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" />
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
    </form>   
</script>
```

I checked every single character in the tutorial and in my code several times, google search for hours, even some experiments like removing the ".edit-user-form", append ";" at the end of the extend, checked similar solutions at SO = didnt help.

I think this is relevant code but I will deliver other piece of code if it will help of course.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems to work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cgurqe3g/), what are you doing differently?

Comment: @mu_is_too_short Thanks for the reply - I forgot to inform its asp.net project so I guess the problem might be in there? (Visual Studio Premium 2013 v.12.0.30110 Update 1).

Comment: I solved it by creating new empty asp.net project and copy the whole code into new blank html page. It works - so the problem must be in some auto imported files when you create asp.net Web app (not empty). Thanks for help, I didnt managed to try it on something like jsfiddle or remote server... :)